# c#,shared folder,windows server

Tags: c#, database, excel

I need a help there is an application which users put excel sheet in shared folder and it moves to another shared folder in another server and then file contents are copied to database and users can view the contents in website.The application has log if any error in file it has been written in log now a days i am getting some frequent error that files are not moving to database and the error is "**External table is not in expected format**" please note that we are using the same code since two years and no change has been made and users are using the excel 2007 since two years.can anyone help on this.

Comment: See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Post code or whatever you need to make it reproducible from my side. What format is it, what file extension does it have (xls, xlsx)?

Comment: the extension used is .xlsx and as and there has been no changes in the code since two years if you need code i will post it and error started coming frequently for the past one month